# jVectormap display state abbrevation on US map by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

I'm trying to display state abbreviations on US-Map by default. I'm using jVectormap. Is there any specific property of the map object to do so?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing in JVectorMap but you can create your own list of abbreviations with the code of each states.

```
listAbbre = { "someCode": "someAbbreviation", "someCode": "someAbbreviation", ... }
```

Then you can use it in onRegionLabelShow property:

```
onRegionLabelShow: function (event, label, code) {
    if (listAbbre.hasOwnProperty(code))
    {
        label.html(listAbbre[code]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I'm trying to show the Labels by default. onRegionLabelShow is only used when the label is shown on hover.

Comment: Ho ok, I misunderstood. If i find something i will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

```
// @flow
export const STATE_TO_ABR_MAP = {
    Arizona: 'AZ',
    Alabama: 'AL',
    Alaska: 'AK',
    Arkansas: 'AR',
    California: 'CA',
    Colorado: 'CO',
    Connecticut: 'CT',
    Delaware: 'DE',
    Florida: 'FL',
    Georgia: 'GA',
    Hawaii: 'HI',
    Idaho: 'ID',
    Illinois: 'IL',
    Indiana: 'IN',
    Iowa: 'IA',
    Kansas: 'KS',
    Kentucky: 'KY',
    Louisiana: 'LA',
    Maine: 'ME',
    Maryland: 'MD',
    Massachusetts: 'MA',
    Michigan: 'MI',
    Minnesota: 'MN',
    Mississippi: 'MS',
    Missouri: 'MO',
    Montana: 'MT',
    Nebraska: 'NE',
    Nevada: 'NV',
    'New Hampshire': 'NH',
    'New Jersey': 'NJ',
    'New Mexico': 'NM',
    'New York': 'NY',
    'North Carolina': 'NC',
    'North Dakota': 'ND',
    Ohio: 'OH',
    Oklahoma: 'OK',
    Oregon: 'OR',
    Pennsylvania: 'PA',
    'Rhode Island': 'RI',
    'South Carolina': 'SC',
    'South Dakota': 'SD',
    Tennessee: 'TN',
    Texas: 'TX',
    Utah: 'UT',
    Vermont: 'VT',
    Virginia: 'VA',
    Washington: 'WA',
    'West Virginia': 'WV',
    Wisconsin: 'WI',
    Wyoming: 'WY',
};

export const ABR_TO_STATES_MAP = {
    AZ: 'Arizona',
    AL: 'Alabama',
    AK: 'Alaska',
    AR: 'Arkansas',
    CA: 'California',
    CO: 'Colorado',
    CT: 'Connecticut',
    DE: 'Delaware',
    FL: 'Florida',
    GA: 'Georgia',
    HI: 'Hawaii',
    ID: 'Idaho',
    IL: 'Illinois',
    IN: 'Indiana',
    IA: 'Iowa',
    KS: 'Kansas',
    KY: 'Kentucky',
    LA: 'Louisiana',
    ME: 'Maine',
    MD: 'Maryland',
    MA: 'Massachusetts',
    MI: 'Michigan',
    MN: 'Minnesota',
    MS: 'Mississippi',
    MO: 'Missouri',
    MT: 'Montana',
    NE: 'Nebraska',
    NV: 'Nevada',
    NH: 'New Hampshire',
    NJ: 'New Jersey',
    NM: 'New Mexico',
    NY: 'New York',
    NC: 'North Carolina',
    ND: 'North Dakota',
    OH: 'Ohio',
    OK: 'Oklahoma',
    OR: 'Oregon',
    PA: 'Pennsylvania',
    RI: 'Rhode Island',
    SC: 'South Carolina',
    SD: 'South Dakota',
    TN: 'Tennessee',
    TX: 'Texas',
    UT: 'Utah',
    VT: 'Vermont',
    VA: 'Virginia',
    WA: 'Washington',
    WV: 'West Virginia',
    WI: 'Wisconsin',
    WY: 'Wyoming',
};
```

To use, you can just do

```
const abbreviation = STATE_TO_ABR_MAP[stateName];
const stateName = ABR_TO_STATES_MAP[abbreviation];
```